# Reduce levels from factor variable

Tags: r, variables, reduce, levels

I have to do a random forest in a large train set but I can't use a variable with more of 53 levels.

The factor variable (`train$tip`) I need to reduce has 150 levels (KHC, KTF, KGL, ...). How can I (quickly) remove (or hold only 53 levels) levels that appear few times and hold ones with more numerosity?

Have I to write all names of levels I see there are few times or is there a faster method?

```
train <- train[!train$tip == "KTF", ]
```

Comment: You can use `tbl <- table(train$tip)` and select based on the frequency i.e. `subset(train levels(tip) %in% names(tbl[tbl > 50]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
train <- train[train$tip %in% names(sort(table(train$tip), decreasing = TRUE))[1:53], ]
```

`table()` computes the frequency of levels; `sort()` orders them in decreasing order; `names()` gets the level rather than the frequency; and `[` selects only the first 53.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add names ; see my edit, it should work now

Comment: now it works! thanks. how can i remove now levels with 0 obs from variable tip? I see all 150 levels in str(train$tip)

Comment: You could also use `droplevels()`